# How do I filter tag messages eclipse?

Tags: android

I am running an app on a phone, I have defined this:

```
private static final String TAG = "111";
```

When I press a button I call this:

```
  Log.d(TAG, "in push to talk on: 111 ");
```

However I don't see anything relating to 111 in the logcat output, I tried to create my own filter with a tag of 111, but nothing appears in this tab? How can I see these tag messages in logcat?

EDIT: i can see the messages if I change them to log.e weirdly.

Comment: 1. Make sure "All messages (no filters)" selected in Logcat view in Eclipse

Comment: that is selected, i really dont understand why they dont show at all

Comment: Do you have ANDROID_LOG_TAGS environment variable defined at your PC? It can control logcat verbose level, I think its global for all system. Can you see same messages out of eclipse?

Comment: I do not know what that tag is, at the moment I have the mode set to verbose yet the only debugs i can see are log.e, not log.d.

Comment: If you execute adb logcat in commandline could you see all messages or only e?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the filter level in your eclipse?, check that the dropdown button has `verbose` or `debug` selected. If you have already selected `warning` or `error`, you will see no output.

Comment: It is at verbose yep!

Comment: I can see the button is pressed, all it does is run a toast and then log a message when i press a button. the toast pops up fine.

Comment: i can see the messages if I change them to log.e